# Keyboard layout of internal and external not matching

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard

I make a new post because all I find is people wanting this, but I got it and it is annoying:

In short, I have an external keyboard (not Mac) on my docking station that I use with my Mac. I am a programmer and it became annoying when <kbd>{</kbd> <kbd>}</kbd> and <kbd><</kbd><kbd>></kbd> came into place, which I use a lot. Most importantly, <kbd><</kbd><kbd>></kbd> on the internal Mac keyboard is right next to Shift, but the same key on the external keyboard is <kbd>§</kbd><kbd>°</kbd>. I checked the settings and it is ISO, and language-wise I just have one option for Swedish (which is my layout).

Any ideas how that happened?

Comment: Are both keyboards physically Swedish ISO, just one Mac, one PC?

Comment: Yes, both are Swedish ISO. I just found Ukelele and it actually showed me what happened: the key on top of TAP and the one next to LEFT SHIFT are exchanged, but only for the external one. I find this very strange that they are not matching. The "change keyboard type" button is also gone, not that it would change anything, since I am even more convinced now that it is not ANSI

Comment: For some reason your machine thinks the external keyboard is ANSI instead of ISO. Karabiner can probably help.